# create set of gulp tasks at runtime

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to create a set of gulp tasks dynamically (at runtime) and after that I want to execute them.

So the default task executes in series task called `createTasks` which I thought would create all my tasks in array `tasks` and then execute the function returned by `gulp.series(tasks)`.

Unfortunately that generates an error:

> VM40 assert.js:42 Uncaught AssertionError: One or more tasks should be combined using series or parallel

The code looks like this:

```
// Gulp 4
var gulp = require('gulp');

var tasks = [];
const fileArray = ['task1', 'task2'];

debugger;
gulp.task('createTasks', function(done) {
for (var key in fileArray)
{
    gulp.task(fileArray[key], function(done) {
        console.log("I was called");
    });
    tasks.push(fileArray[key]);
}});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series('createTasks', gulp.series(tasks)));
```

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `gulp.series` expecting the tasks as individual parameters, rather than receiving them all in a single array parameter?

If your setup supports ES 6, this should work:

`gulp.task('default', gulp.series('createTasks', gulp.series(...tasks)))`;

If not, you could try this one:

`gulp.task('default', gulp.series('createTasks', gulp.series.apply(this, tasks)))`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `createTasks` as gulp task. You just iterate over list of task and add the task name into the array and call the series method as `apply`.

```
// Gulp 4
var gulp = require('gulp');

var tasks = [];
const fileArray = ['task1', 'task2'];

for (var key in fileArray){
    gulp.task(fileArray[key], function(done) {
        console.log("I was called");
    });
    tasks.push(fileArray[key]);
};


gulp.task('default', gulp.series.apply(this,tasks));
```

Comment: Sorry I am putting it in comments but I don't seem to have reply button.
Thanks, I had to put the inside of for loop into IIFE:
    gulp.task('createTasks', function(done) {
    'for (var key in fileArray)
    {
  gulp.task(fileArray[key], function(done) {
   console.log("I was called");
   done();
  });
  tasks.push(fileArray[key]);
 }});'